# Adding Larger Icon On Excel 2007 Ribbon Button

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I've got an Excel 2007 VBA script that adds a button to the ribbon, but unfortunately the icon is tiny.  I tried several different FaceId's, but they all seemed to add tiny icon buttons.  Is there a way to load in some of the newer 2007 size icons?

Here is a snippet of the code that I've got loaded in ThisWorkbook:

```
Set NewButton = NewToolbar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
With NewButton
     .FaceId = 752
    .TooltipText = "Convert XLS Files to CSVs"
    .OnAction = "XLSTOCSV"
```

Thanks for any insights about increasing the size of the icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the NewButton.Height and NewButton.Width to set the size of the button. Other properties can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa171351(office.11).aspx)

Hope this helps

EDIT:

Try this:

```
Set NewButton= .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, Id:=YourFaceID)
```

I'm not sure, but that might do the auto sizing for you

EDIT 2:

If it helps, try making a ribon if you are using buttons. The coding is really simple if you know basic XML. An example is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" > 
    <ribbon> 
        <tabs> 
            <tab id="myTab" label="New Tab"> 
                <group id="group1" label="New Buttons"> 
                    <button id="MyButton" label="My Button" imageMso="HappyFace" size="large" onAction="myButton_ClickHandler" /> 
                </group> 
            </tab> 
        </tabs> 
    </ribbon> 
</customUI>
```

This creates a ribbon that looks like this:

[image: Excel Ribbon]

Simple steps to getting this:

1. Open a new excel workbook
2. Save it as an Excel Add In (*.xlam)
3. Download this freeware:  [XML UI editor](http://openxmldeveloper.org/articles/CustomUIeditor.aspx)
4. Paste the code above into it
5. Save it
6. Open Excel
7. Go to Excel Options > Add ins > Go  and tick whatever you called your addin
8. Have fun with that :)

A few notes on the code: The OnAction is the name of the sub in your excell addin that will be called when that button is clicked. The rest is pretty self explanatory

For more info, look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa338202.aspx)

Comment: Bummer...I guess I was hoping that there existed a way to load the larger default icons within Excel 2007 or to have have it autosize to fill the whole available area by default...oh well...

Comment: If you want it to fill the whole available area then just set the height and width to be the same as the container's height and width. As far as defining a 'default', why not create some default sizes or a default button to coppy off. Give me a minute tho, i think there is a 'copy template' funciton